# How to convert a list with a string of numbers into a list of intergers?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of lists and inside the lists are strings of multiple numbers. For example,
`[['34,53,53,21'], ['43,65,12,53'], ['54,23,31,34']]`

and I want the result to look like:
`[[34,53,53,21], [43,65,12,53], [54,23,31,34]]`
with all integers inside. I've tried numerous code, but keep getting different error messages.

Also, what about if some of the interior numbers were a float? Such as:
`[['34,53.09,53.56,21.98'], ['43,65.67,12.45,53.45'], ['54,23.34,31.23,34.76']]`

Comment: You should have posted what you tried so we may correct your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> L = [['34,53,53,21'], ['43,65,12,53'], ['54,23,31,34']]
>>> [[int(y) for y in x[0].split(',')] for x in L]
[[34, 53, 53, 21], [43, 65, 12, 53], [54, 23, 31, 34]]
```

For floats:

```
>>> L = [['34,53.09,53.56,21.98'], ['43,65.67,12.45,53.45'], ['54,23.34,31.23,34.76']]
>>> [[float(y) for y in x[0].split(',')] for x in L]
[[34.0, 53.09, 53.56, 21.98], [43.0, 65.67, 12.45, 53.45], [54.0, 23.34, 31.23, 34.76]]
```

Comment: What would you do if a some of the numbers were floats inside the string such as [['34, 53.33, 53.09']]?

Comment: @JimDavis: Then just do `...float(y) for y in x[0]...`.

Comment: @JimDavis Oh are you saying some are floats, some are ints, etc. actually you could just use `ast.literal_eval` on `x[0]` since it's already the right structure for a tuple. But do you have a problem with all of them being `float`s? @JoelCornett suggested the right thing

Comment: Yeah, some are floats and some are ints. They could all be floats if needed.

Comment: @JimDavis Ok that's the best way

Comment: I changed the int to float, but they are still strings. Here is what I used [[float(y) for y in x[0].split(',')] for x in L]

Comment: @JimDavis Did you assign the result back to the original variable?

Answer (score 3):

```
[[int(y) for y in x[0].split(',')] for x in lst]
```

On python 2.x, you could use:

```
[map(int,x[0].split(',')) for x in lst]
```

And in some ways, having inner list of the strings is inconvenient.  You could use `chain` to remove them:

```
from itertools import chain
[[int(y) for y in x.split(',')] for x in chain.from_iterable(lst)]
```